# Bimserver error

Tags: java, dependencies, maven

I have trouble running *bimserver* on ***eclipse***.

I started by cloning the repo, then import it, from there I can't overcome this error : `Execution add-source of goal org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.10:add-source failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.10.`

I am relatively new to maven, so hope to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Add bimserver as dependency on your pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opensourcebim/bimserver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensourcebim</groupId>
        <artifactId>bimserver</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.21</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```